# Why is a fast change of background-images (animation) so slow on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

In order to animate 3D objects on a website (like a smartphone or a tablet), i change the background-image of a DIV 25 times a second.

This is the Javascript function (jQuery):

```
var playiPhoneVideo = function() {
    window.setTimeout(changeBG, 800);   // delayed starting time
};
var iIndex = 1;
var changeBG = function() {
    $('.iphone').css('background-image', 'url(assets/iphone-ani/iPhone5_'+iIndex+'.png)'); // change BG
    iIndex++;
    if(iIndex <= 41) {
        window.setTimeout(changeBG, 40); // 25 fps
    }

}
```

`setTimeout` with 40 miliseconds to ensure 25 frames a second.
The images are preloaded before the animation/video starts.

Now this performs quite well on all desktop OS's. It performs even better (actually i'm quite suprised how amazingly well it runs) on mobile IE10 (Windows RT).
It runs only ok on iOS (iPad mini).
**It runs unbelievably poor on Android** (Xperia Tablet Z, Sony Tablet S).

What i did trying to maximaze performance:

- changed image file size from 200kb to 20kb (very poor quality)
- slowed down the recursive JS loop by increasing the `setTimeout` to 100 miliseconds (slowmotion)
- used only every second or every fourth image by replacing `iIndex++` with `iIndex = iIndex + 2/4`
- tried to hardware accellerate the DIV with `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` (i know, useless but worth a shot ;-) )

Even with all those optimizations combined the animation ran so poorly. It barely got better.

I have the feeling that this has nothing to do with the images but with the slow Javascript performance of Chrome on Android/Android Browser but i don't know for sure.

Is there any way to optimize my Javascript, my Loop, the Images or anything else to ensure a smooth (and acceptable quality) animation on Android?

Answer (score -1):

Use below settings: It will increase the performance of animations in WebView

```
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

or

You can use ChromeView instead of WebView:

```
https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview
```

Comment: I'm not building an app. I build a website.

Comment: Use jQuery mobile...it is optimized for mobiles